# Static vs. external intrinsics

Tags: c, gcc, static, clang, intrinsics

The Clang 6.0.1 avxintrin.h has the declaration:

```
static __inline __m256i __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS _mm256_set1_epi32(int)
```

GCC 5.5 has:

```
extern __inline __m256i __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, _always_inline__, __artificial__)) _mm256_set1_epi32(int)
```

**Why would one be `extern` and one `static`?** This is showing up for me in an `inline` function that calls `_mm256_set1_epi32`. Clang wants it to be declared `static`:

```
#include <immintrin.h>

inline void SimdBlockBloomFilter_make_mask() {
  _mm256_set1_epi32(1);
}
```

With `-Weverything`:

```
warning: static function '_mm256_set1_epi32' is used in an inline
function with external linkage [-Wstatic-in-inline]
```

This error does *not* show up when compiling with Clang++.

Comment: Probably the people who wrote them didn't think the difference would matter.  The whole point of intrinsics is to fully inline, linkage is irrelevant except as a fallback in case someone takes the address of an intrinsic.  I'm not sure what the right fix would be.

Comment: @PeterCordes I wonder why they even wrote either modifier, `static` or `extern`. They could just do without, it seems.

Comment: `static inline` can be useful in code compiled with `-fPIC`.  Not all compilers agree that `inline foo() { ... }` supercedes symbol interposition for symbols with non-hidden ELF visibility.  So the function might not actually be able to inline.  Other than that, yes `inline foo() { ... }` does mean that no stand-alone definition has to be emitted (assuming the compiler chooses to inline it everywhere), so `static` isn't needed for that.  I'm curious too what other reasons there might be for `static` or `extern` here in C or C++.

Comment: @PeterCordes Your compiler will always emit ordinary function code and symbols for `inline foo()` since the function has external linkage and could be referenced outside the translation unit. But your linker removes that code if it never gets called.

Comment: @user6556709: that's only true for `extern inline` in C, and not at all in C++. 
 https://godbolt.org/z/y2AoK7 shows gcc/clang asm output, before even assembling.  Regular `inline` also promises that every call-site can see the same *definition*.  Current compilers optimize that process by only emitting a stand-alone definition if there's a call-site in the current translation where the compiler chooses not to inline, saving work during compiling and linking. (BTW, I thought that I might get a stand-alone definition while writing my previous comment, but I checked on Godbolt so left it out.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the GCC version, the [`gnu_inline` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-gnu_005finline-function-attribute) is close to the behavior of `static inline` in C99 and later modes.

The C committee ignored the GNU precedent when redefining the meaning of `extern inline`: With the GNU compiler, `extern inline` meant that the compiler should never generate a non-inline copy of the function (even if its address is taken).  In C99, `extern inline` means that a definition in a translation unit completes an `inline` definition in another translation unit.

The GCC version of `<immintrin.h>` uses the `gnu_inline` attribute to get the expected behavior in all compiler modes (C89/C90 and C99 in particular).